# eMMC RAW access in Linux

Tags: linux, embedded

I am trying to do a raw write to the `eMMC` within my embedded system. The device node is `/dev/mmcblk1p1` and I'm trying to copy a binary `example.bin` to a particular address in the `eMMC`, say `0x1000`.

Could someone please help me as to how I can go about this. I am using ARM platform running Linux. Any help would really prove useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?If you want to flash an image to the MMC, your bootloader will have commands to do so, viz.nand.write.

Comment: It's not the boot loader that I am dealing with. I want an application to write a binary file to a particular address in eMMC. If I'm not wrong, the bootloader would be dealing with the kernel image etc. I just want to flash my own binary to an address. Hope this helped..

Comment: I guess you could then write a program to open(/dev/mmcblkp1), seek() to the desired offset corresponding to the eMMC address and start writing your binary file.

Comment: This offset value which is a parameter to fseek(), must it be in hex or decimal? what I mean is if I want to seek to a location, say 0x1000 on the eMMC and flash a binary there, how would the call to fseek() look like?

Comment: fseek(FP,0x1000,SEEK_SET) ?

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with the [dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) command line program. Copying `example.bin` to `/dev/mmcblk1` at an offset of 0x1000 would be done as follows:

```
dd if=example.bin of=/dev/mmcblk1 seek=8
```

The offset of the out file (`/dev/mmcblk1`) is specified with the seek option and is 8 in this example as dd works in blocks of 512 bytes by default. See `man dd` for more info.

This could also be done programmatically in C by using the lseek() function on the open file descriptor of the out file.

Note that in the question the `/dev/mmcblk1p1` file is mentioned, but this is the device node of the first partition on the MMC device (p1). The `/dev/mmcblk1` file is the correct node for the actual MMC device.

Answer (score -5):

You need to mount your device node to the Linux filesystem first.

```
# mount -t msdos /dev/mmcblk1p1 /mnt/
# cp /mnt/libnsl.so /lib/libnsl.so.1
# /mnt/lrz
```

`lrz` is an application which will transfer file using `ZMODEM` protocol. Using `TeraTerm`, open

File -> Transfer -> ZMODEM -> example.bin and click `OK`.

Comment: No this would not work because I want to perform a RAW write to an address. What you have suggested would be over a file system.